# Firestore Security Rules Permission Issue

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, firebase-security

I have documents in firestore collection called 'inventories' of the following structure:

```
{
    creator: string,
    images: string[],
}
```

the creator field is the uid of the user who created the document.

In my firestore rules section I have the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {  
     match /inventories/{inventoryid} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth.id == resource.data.creator;
     }
   }
 }
```

In my ionic application I do the following:

```
this.inventoryCollection = database.collection<Inventory[]>
    ('inventories', ref => ref.where('creator', '==', auth.currentUserId));
```

I get the following error when this executes:

```
Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Is it a problem with my rules? Or is it a problem with my code calling the firestore?

Comment: Have you checked if the current user ID is correct? Maybe tested with hard-coded values?

Comment: @AndréKool The currentUserId is being pulled from the Firebase Auth library, so no hard coded values there. I have marked the answer down below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `request.auth.uid` instead of `request.auth.id`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth

Also, you should divide your rules in two "sub-rules", as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {  
     match /inventories/{inventoryid} {
       allow read: if request.auth.id == resource.data.creator;
       allow write: if request.auth.id == request.resource.data.creator;
     }
   }
 }
```

Note the use of `request.resource` for the `write` rule.

This is very well explained in the official following video about Firestore Security Rules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw

Comment: I hate myself. Initially I wasn't filtering using the where clause so I was getting the permission error. So in my attempt to fix that I must have mistyped the uid field. Thanks very much.