# Is there a way to force a Firestore document to include truthful metadata?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to include truthful metadata about who wrote a document and when it was created.
In this answer you can force certain fields to be included, e.g. timestamp, UID
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57486776/1350796
However, I am not sure if there is a way to prevent a malicious client from faking that metadata. I am aware I can send my write requests through a server where I force this modification, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it entirely in Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to enforce anything (other than built in limits) on document writes is through [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  Your rules can require that client must provide valid data.  Not everything is possible, but you can certainly require that a field's value must match the user's UID, and you can require that timestamps must be within a certain range (or must be provided as a server value timestamp).

See:

- [Firestore per-field security rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380783/firestore-per-field-security-rule)
- [Firestore Security Rules Permission Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419290/firestore-security-rules-permission-issue)
- [Firestore Security Rules: If timestamp (FieldValue.serverTimestamp) equals now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783812/firestore-security-rules-if-timestamp-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-equals-now)

Note that security rules are only in force for web and mobile clients. Backend code bypasses security rules, with the assumption that the code is doing its own validation.